# How send a html file direclty to the printer in java

Tags: swing

I'm using this to send a htlm file direclty to printer and it says invalid flavour which means that the printer does not support the formats. Any one have an idea to do this..

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Input the file
    FileInputStream textStream = null; 
    try { 
        textStream = new FileInputStream("./some.html"); 
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ffne) { 
    } 
    if (textStream == null) { 
        return; 
    } 
    // Set the document type
    DocFlavor myFormat  = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.TEXT_HTML_HOST;

    // Create a Doc
    Doc myDoc = new SimpleDoc(textStream, myFormat , null);         
    // Build a set of attributes
    PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet(); 
    aset.add(new Copies(1)); 
    //aset.add(MediaSize.NA.LEGAL);
    aset.add(Sides.ONE_SIDED); 
    // discover the printers that can print the format according to the
    // instructions in the attribute set
    PrintService services = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
        //PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(myFormat, aset);
    // Create a print job from one of the print services
    //System.out.println("====5======="+service.get);
    //if (services.length > 0) { 
    for (int i = 0; i < services.getSupportedDocFlavors().length; i++) {
        System.out.println("====getSupportedDocFlavors======="+services.getSupportedDocFlavors()[i]);
    }

        DocPrintJob job = services.createPrintJob(); 
        try { 
            job.print(myDoc, aset); 
        } catch (PrintException pe) {
            System.out.println("====PrintException======="+pe);
        } 
    //} 

}
```

---

It says

```
sun.print.PrintJobFlavorException: invalid flavor
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to force printer to handle (render) HTML document onto the paper. It will never work that way. And ofcourse the flavor you are sending is not supported.

First of all you need to render HTML into some graphical representation and then send it to printer. There are no good cross-platform tools for Java that could render modern HTML pages. But there is one in JavaFX and i guess you could use it to handle the task.

About printing the final image you can read here:
http://www.apl.jhu.edu/~hall/java/Swing-Tutorial/Swing-Tutorial-Printing.html
or see the code here:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/2D-Graphics-GUI/PrintanImagetoprintdirectly.htm
or just find any other resource - there are a lot about printing.

Answer (score 0):

public class POSPrinter {

```
private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(POSPrinter.class);

public POSPrinter(Long billID, String printMode) {
}

/**
 * 
 * This method prints the specified PDF to specified printer under specified
 * 
 * job name
 * 
 * 
 * 
 * @param filePath
 *            Path of PDF file
 * 
 * @param printerName
 *            Printer name
 * 
 * @param jobName
 *            Print job name
 * 
 * @throws IOException
 * 
 * @throws PrinterException
 */

public void printPDF(String filePath, String printerName, String jobName,
        Integer height, Integer width) throws IOException, PrinterException {

    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);

    byte[] pdfContent = new byte[fileInputStream.available()];

    fileInputStream.read(pdfContent, 0, fileInputStream.available());

    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(pdfContent);

    final PDFFile pdfFile = new PDFFile(buffer);

    Printable printable = new Printable() {

        public int print(Graphics graphics, PageFormat pageFormat,
                int pageIndex) throws PrinterException {

            int pagenum = pageIndex + 1;

            if ((pagenum >= 1) && (pagenum <= pdfFile.getNumPages())) {

                Graphics2D graphics2D = (Graphics2D) graphics;

                PDFPage page = pdfFile.getPage(pagenum);

                Rectangle imageArea = new Rectangle(

                (int) pageFormat.getImageableX(),

                (int) pageFormat.getImageableY(),

                (int) pageFormat.getImageableWidth(),

                (int) pageFormat.getImageableHeight());

                graphics2D.translate(0, 0);

                PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(page, graphics2D,
                        imageArea, null, null);

                try {
                    page.waitForFinish();

                    pdfRenderer.run();

                } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }

                return PAGE_EXISTS;

            } else {

                return NO_SUCH_PAGE;

            }

        }

    };

    PrinterJob printJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

    PageFormat pageFormat = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob().defaultPage();

    printJob.setJobName(jobName);

    Book book = new Book();

    book.append(printable, pageFormat, pdfFile.getNumPages());

    printJob.setPageable(book);

    Paper paper = new Paper();

    paper.setSize(width, height);
    paper.setImageableArea(0, 0, paper.getWidth(), paper.getHeight());

    // pageFormat
    pageFormat.setPaper(paper);

    // PrintService[] printServices = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();
    //
    // for (int count = 0; count < printServices.length; ++count) {
    //
    // if (printerName.equalsIgnoreCase(printServices[count].getName())) {
    //
    // printJob.setPrintService(printServices[count]);
    //
    // break;
    //
    // }
    //
    // }

    PrintService printService = PrintServiceLookup
            .lookupDefaultPrintService();
    printJob.setPrintService(printService);

    printJob.print();

}
```